# Code completion in RubyMine/Intellj IDEA for coffeescript global variables

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, autocomplete, coffeescript, rubymine

I am trying to separate my coffeescript code into several files. I created a global object to share the code between files(see below). Unfortunately RubyMine, which I am currently using does not understand such approach and does not provide code completion. Is there any workaround for that?

**Code**

```
// --- global.js ---
// define root namespace
if (typeof _ === "undefined") {
    var _ = {};
}

# --- utils.coffee ---
# sprockets requires
#= require global

class _.MyException

# --- somecode.coffee ---
#= require utils
class SomeClass
  f: ->
    throw new _.MyException
```